# TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a newbie on tensorflow and learning from very beginning. I tried to read csv file and decode using `tf.decode_csv` and I am trying to understand `batch` and `graph` through examples.

My example csv is 8 datas and 1 logistic shape, separated by comma.
This is first four rows of my file.

```
-0.294118,0.487437,0.180328,-0.292929,0,0.00149028,-0.53117,-0.0333333,0
-0.882353,-0.145729,0.0819672,-0.414141,0,-0.207153,-0.766866,-0.666667,1
-0.0588235,0.839196,0.0491803,0,0,-0.305514,-0.492741,-0.633333,0
-0.882353,-0.105528,0.0819672,-0.535354,-0.777778,-0.162444,-0.923997,0,1
```

My code is,

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['data-03-diabetes.csv'],
                                                shuffle=False,
                                                name='filename_queue')
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.]]
xy = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim=',')

train_x_batch, train_y_batch = tf.train.batch([xy[0:-1], xy[-1:]],
                                              batch_size=10)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 8])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8,1]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='bias')

hypothesis = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)
cost = -tf.reduce_mean(Y * tf.log(hypothesis) + (1 - Y) * tf.log(1 - hypothesis))

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(cost)

predicted = tf.cast(hypothesis > 0.5, dtype = tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(predicted, Y), dtype=tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    feed = {X: train_x_batch, Y: train_y_batch}
    for step in range(10001):
        x_batch, y_batch = sess.run([train_x_batch, train_y_batch])
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(step, sess.run(cost, feed_dict=feed))
    h, c, a = sess.run([hypothesis, predicted, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
    print("\nHypothesis", h, "\nCorrect (Y):", c, "\nAccuracy", a)
```

and then I got this error code,

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

Does it mean that I declared wrong `placeholder` and `Variable`??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the entire error message? It should include information about the line of code where the error arose.

Comment: @mrry In line 41, in <module> print(step, see.run(cost, feed_dict=feed))   TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.

Comment: That seems to be a different error. However, you can fix it by defining `X = train_x_batch` and `Y = train_y_batch` instead of creating `tf.placeholder()` ops for `X` and `Y`, then removing the `feed_dict` from the `sess.run()` call.

Comment: @mrry Thank your advice. I keep reading documents and thought I made mistake on line#5 then I fixed. Is your advice for my `TypeError`?

Comment: Yes, instead of trying to feed a `tf.Tensor` with a `tf.Tensor` (which isn't allowed, as the error message says), you can connect the outputs of `tf.train.batch()` directly to your model computation.

Comment: @mrry Okay. As you mentioned I fixed my `X`,`Y` and `sess.run()`. However its value is different from if I use `np.loadtxt` instead of `tf.train.string_input_producer`. Is it because I don't have placeholder?

Comment: @mrry I figured out! However I still need to understand this one. Thank you for help